# What are the possible magnetic quantum numbers of silver?

Tags: physical-chemistry, atomic-structure

What are all the possible quantum numbers **m<sub>l</sub>** and **m<sub>s</sub>** of the electrons in the outermost **s** orbital of silver? I'm new to this concept. Can anyone walk me through this?

Answer (score 1):

Silver has electronic configuration as **[Kr] 4d<sup>10</sup> 5s<sup>1</sup>** .
The **s** orbital ( **5s** ) has only one electron. And the **s** orbital here has **n** = 5 (as it is in the fifth period) and **l** = 0 .
 
The **s** orbital is symmetric in space (sphere) which has only one orientation and hence has no "different" orientations  each of which is represented by a particular value of **m<sub>l</sub>**. So **m<sub>l</sub>** can take only one value and that is 0.( If this was a **p** orbital which could take 3 different orientations, **m<sub>l</sub>** would take 3 values -> -1,0,1. In general an orbital with azimuthal quantum number l, **m<sub>l</sub>** would take 2**l**+1 values of **m<sub>l</sub>**  ranging from **-l** to **+l** )
The quantum number **m<sub>s</sub>** represents the spin. It can either be +1/2 or -1/2.
Hence ,  **m<sub>l</sub>** =  0 amd **m<sub>s</sub>** = +1/2 or -1/2.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 quantum numbers.

**n** - *Principal quantum number* with values 1,2,3,4... - in simple words look at the row in periodic table and this is the max value of n for a particular atom.

**l** - *Azimuthal quantum number*, has always values from 0 to (n-1). In simple words it representsthe type of orbital (s, p, d, f). Look at the following table.

[image]

**m<sub>l</sub>** - *magnetic quantum number* distinguishes the orbitals available within a subshell and has values from -l to +l. In simple words, each orbital wavefunction has a specific shape (photo above). There is 1 s orbital, 5 p orbitals, 10 d orbitals and so on. This numbers points to one of the orbitals.

**m<sub>s</sub>** - *spin quantum number*, represents the spin of an electron. Values +1/2 and -1/2.

---

Back to your question - quantum number of outermost s orbital of silver. Silver has an electron configuration [Kr] 4d<sup>10</sup> 5s<sup>1</sup>.

**n = 5** as silver is in the 5th row (row is called period).

**l = 0** for s orbital

**ms = 0** as there is only 1 s orbital

**ml = +1/2 or -1/2**

I hope this explains your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have four quantum numbers: n, l, m<sub>l</sub> and m<sub>s</sub>.

The relationship between them is

n = 1, 2, 3... (theoretically speaking, up to infinite)

l = 0, 1, 2... n-1

-l <= m<sub>l</sub> <= l (that means, m<sub>l</sub> can assume all integer values between -l and l, including 0).

m<sub>s</sub> can be either 1/2 or -1/2.

l gives the "shape" of the orbital, and chemists give nicknames to the orbitals:

l = 0 is called s, l = 1 is called p, l = 2 is called d, l = 3 is called f, and so on (l = 4 is g, l = 5 is h, you got the idea)

Now, Silver is in the fifth period, therefore your n = 5. 
Since we are only interested in the s orbitals, we have n = 5, l = 0 (for the reason given above). Since l = 0, then also m<sub>l</sub> is 0. 
You have two electrons in the s orbital, therefore you have both 1/2 and  -1/2 for m<sub>s</sub>.

Therefore, your quantum numbers are n = 5, l = 0, m<sub>l</sub> = 0, m<sub>s</sub> = +1/2 and - 1/2.

I hope this helps!